# when to use memory optimized instance vs elastic cache?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, azure-sql-database

Hi all I am new to cloud computing and have a basic question. My application is currently on premise and I have been using a lot of memory for limited cores. I dont have that kind of memory to core ratio available on cloud (AWS or Azure). Can i use options such as elastic cache along with memory-optimized instances such as r4?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: I have not deployed it yet. not sure which solution to implement.

Comment: Then you're way too early to be asking on Stack Overflow. This is off-topic.

Comment: Sorry, i am new so didnt realize that. Which forum should i ask then, can you pls guide

Comment: This is a general advice question that’s better suited to discussion forums like [Quora](http://quora.com), or Reddit’s [`/r/programming`](http://reddit.com/r/programming/).